# Matching a pattern in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to match a string which is 9 characters long and will always have digits.

The pattern I am trying to match is to see if the string is all 0s or all 1s or all 2s and so on upto all 9s.

Can someone help me write this. I just had to consider 0s and 9s and i hard coded those and it works fine. But surely there's an easier way to do this.

Can someone help please?

Comment: If your set of patterns is that bounded (and unlikely to change much) then a lookup table is almost certainly the best solution. Regular expressions could (with alternation and bounded repetition) express these patterns fairly cleanly also. Lua patterns can't though. The "cleverest" non-hard-coded idea I've got, offhand, is a match on nine digits followed by grabbing the first digit and searching the string for anything that isn't that digit.

Comment: Etan, that's one of the approaches i wanted to take, but was waiting if there were any other possible ways in LUA.
I'll try what David had suggested and if that doesn't work I'll go with this approach.

Comment: @EtanReisner , can you please post your comment as an answer please, I ended up using a table per your suggestion and would like to mark your answer as an accepted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this pattern: `((%d)%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2)`.

As Etan mentioned in a comment, you can also use query a table:

`allowed={ ["000000000""]=true, ["111111111""]=true, ..., ["999999999"]=true }`

Then `s` matches one of the allowed patterns if `allowed[s]` is true.

Comment: Great use of the captures, May want to add ^ and $ to the pattern, if by chance you get something like `"a111111111  "`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your inputs will be something like

```
111111111
222222222
```

Which means you can use the following regex to match it:

```
^(\d)\1{8}$
```

See an example of it [here](https://regex101.com/r/dY6jI3/2). Basically we are just capturing the first digit and seeing if it repeats 8 more times

Comment: David, thanks for the regex, I'll try that in a bit and let you know if that works in LUA.

Comment: @SalmanSyed Sorry I wasn't able to give you the lua code for it, I don't actually know lua

Comment: I am a c# person myself but trying to resolve this one off case.

Comment: lua, itself, doesn't support regular expressions. You would need a regex library for lua for this to work.

Comment: @Etan, thanks for the update, thought of using LPEG but i have got serious limitations on my side of the tool here for adding libraries.
FYI, this is being used in IBM optim

Comment: LPEG isn't regular expression but would, absolutely, let you do what you wanted to do here easily enough.

Comment: @SalmanSyed Does your setup have a C compiler and does it allow you to build modules from source and require it in your lua environment? If it does then you can use LPeg.